# How to handle the mouse wheel button event in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mousewheel

I have a project which uses EXT.NET framework for the controls. I'm currently working on the behavior of closing the panel tabs such as Google Chrome and all the modern browsers does.

I couldn't find the answer to this. What is the ASCII value for the mouse scroll wheel button? How can I handle this event in C# ASP.NET?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you want to get `mouse wheel event`.

Comment: Yes, I do... but I couldn't find anything... even the ASCII value for this button, which I suppose that exist!. I don't need the scroll event... only the button on the wheel.

Comment: Why would you think that ASCII, which predates the common mouse by a significant margin (never mind that prehistoric mice did not have scroll wheels, and couldn't even decide if they needed one, two or three buttons), would have a code word specifically allocated out of it's limited 128-word dictionary for events concerning objects that didn't exist yet?

Comment: Change the question if you like... how do you handle the event if you're saying that doesn't exist any ASCII code for this button? ASP.NET does provide any event handler for this, so that's why i'm asking...because "I don't know"!

Comment: @MauroBilotti I know nothing about EXT.NET, ASP.NET or C#, but I do know that the "button" action of a scroll wheel on a mouse is generally just treated as another button... So watch for the button events, and check the button identification to see which button it was... In the mouse you have pictured, you probably have button 1 on the left, button two on the right, so the scroll wheel may be button 3, or maybe 4 or higher - I can't tell if that other button-like thing under the scroll wheel is also a button...

Answer (score 0):

working on Firefox, Explorer and Chrome:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).mousedown(function(e) {
            closeTab(e);
        });
    });


    function closeTab(e) {
        if (!e) {
            e = window.event;
            e.which = e.keyCode;
        }

        if(e.which == 2){
            var tbpPrincipal = <%= tbpPrincipal.ClientID %>;
            var activeTab = null;
            for (var i = 0; i < tbpPrincipal.items.length; i++) {
                var currentTab = tbpPrincipal.items.items[i];
                if (e.target.innerText == currentTab.title || e.target.textContent == currentTab.title) {
                    activeTab = currentTab;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (activeTab) {
                var activeTabIndex = tbpPrincipal.items.findIndex('id', activeTab.id);
                tbpPrincipal.remove(activeTabIndex);
            }

        }
        return true;// to allow the browser to know that we handled it.
    }
```